# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $animateProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

This should be a simple issue, eveything was working fine. Suddenly i am stuck with this error, i tried to fix it by following angular website. It dit not help me . Here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**App.Js:**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('DuoDiginRt', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);
 routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
 $stateProvider          
             .state('dashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard',
                    templateUrl: 'Charts.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
               })
       });
 routerApp.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
 function($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.gridsterOptions = {
                    margins: [20, 20],
                    columns: 4,
                    draggable: {
                        handle: 'h3'
                    }
                };
  $scope.dashboards = {
                '1': {
                        id: '1',
                icon: 'images/icons/chart_line.png',
                        name: 'Home',
                        widgets: [
                         {
                            col: 0,
                            row: 0,
                            sizeY: 1,
                            sizeX: 1,
                            icon: 'images/icons/chart_line.png',
                            name: "Stocks per store"
                         }
                         ]
                 }
                };
                $scope.clear = function() {
                    $scope.dashboard.widgets = [];
                };

                $scope.addWidget = function() {
                    $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
                        name: "New Chart",
                        sizeX: 1,
                        sizeY: 1
                    });
                };

                $scope.remove = function(widget) {
                    $scope.dashboard.widgets.splice($scope.dashboard.widgets.indexOf(widget), 1);
                };

                 $scope.openSettings = function(widget) {
                    $modal.open({
                        scope: $scope,
                        templateUrl: 'chart_settings.html',
                        controller: 'chartSettingsCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            widget: function() {
                                return widget;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
            $scope.ZoomIn = function () {  
                var ZoomInValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("container").style.zoom) + 10 + '%'  
                document.getElementById("container").style.zoom = ZoomInValue;  
                return false;  
            }  

            $scope.ZoomOut = function () {  
                var ZoomOutValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("container").style.zoom) - 10 + '%'  
                document.getElementById("container").style.zoom = ZoomOutValue;  
                return false;  
            }

            $scope.Zoomorg = function () {  
                var ZoomOutValue = parseInt(100) + '%'  
                document.getElementById("container").style.zoom = ZoomOutValue;  
                return false;  
            }

            $scope.openBox = function(){
                $("#toolboxControl").css("left","0px");
                $("#openbox").css("display","none");
                $("#closebox").css("display","block");
            }

            $scope.closeBox = function(){
                $("#toolboxControl").css("left","-250px");
                $("#closebox").css("display","none");
                $("#openbox").css("display","block");
            }

            $scope.vopenBox = function(){
                $("#variablepanel").css("right","0px");
                $("#vopenbox").css("display","none");
                $("#vclosebox").css("display","block");
            }

            $scope.vcloseBox = function(){
                $("#variablepanel").css("right","-250px");
                $("#vclosebox").css("display","none");
                $("#vopenbox").css("display","block");
            }

                 $scope.$watch('selectedDashboardId', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                        $scope.dashboard = $scope.dashboards[newVal];
                    } else {
                        $scope.dashboard = $scope.dashboards[1];
                    }
                 });

                 // init dashboard
                 $scope.selectedDashboardId = '1';

            }
          ])
```

**HTML:**

```
 <body   ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
            <div id="main_wrapper">         
                <div id="toolboxControl">
                    <div id="toolbaropener">
                        <div id="openbox" ng-click="openBox()">></div>
                        <div id="closebox" ng-click="closeBox()"><</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="containerChart">
                      <ul>
                          <li>
                          <a  ng-click="addWidget()" href="#controlflow">Charts</a>
                          <div id="controlflow" class="containerChart">
                            <input ng-model="searchCommonValue" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search controls...">
                            <div plumb-menu-item ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets | filter : searchCommonValue" class="menu-item" data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" data-title="{{widget.name}}" draggable>
                                <img class="toolheader" src="{{widget.Icon}}">
                                <div class="toolcontent">{{widget.name}}</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="container" class="drop-container" ng-click="addEvent($event)" droppable>
                    <div plumb-item class="item"  style="margin: 20px; top: 60px; left: 200px; height: 300px; width: 500px;" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.sizeX, 'top':widget.sizeY }"
                        data-identifier="{{widget.id}}">
                        <div class="box" ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
                        <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                            <a title="settings" ng-click="openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                            <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <!--  <bars data="40,4,55,15,16,33,52,20"></bars> -->
                        <!--  <bargraph id="d3bar" datajson="sample.json"
                        xaxis-name = "Year"
                        xaxis-pos = "905"
                        yaxis-name = "Frequency"
                        yaxis-pos = "12"
                        d3-format= ".0%"> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div post-render></div>
                <span ng-init="init()"></span>  
        </div>
```

Comment: which version of angularjs you are using ?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.11/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/d3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Why are you loading angular twice (first and last line of scripts? 1.2.15 and 1.0.6 ... could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen **Unknown Provider** issues as well when I introduced `ngAnimate` into a project with an older release of Angular.  Your best bet is to use the version of `ngAnimate` equal to the current version of Angular in your project.

They seem to be released at the same time.

Look at the version of Angular (at the top of the JS file) and determine when it was released and find the matching release for ngAnimate.

It is also possible that Barang can cause this issue in Chrome (and, possibly Firefox) with older versions.  Disable, if using.

**UPDATE**:

Upon looking at the code, there are two versions of Angular being loaded; version 1.0.6 and 1.2.15.  You can only load one version.

Comment: how can i check that? btw am not using ngAnimate anywhere

Comment: I just updated ... it's something I've seen; also, look at any plugins that are Angular related ... try disabling them, even if you are not using them at the moment.

Comment: It is the same with firefox too

Comment: `$animateProvider` is part of the `ngAnimate` functionality.  You may not have the code in your application, but if you are loading it, it could cause an issue.  It COULD be loaded as part of a plug in, such as **Batarang**.